# How to delete a row if it meets a criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a macro that deletes the row which I've previously selected.

I want the macro to delete the entire row unless I select row 11 or 12. In that case I only want to delete the content of the row and keep the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
with selection
   if not intersect(.cells, .parent.range("11:12")) is nothing then
       .cells.entirerow.clearcontent   'use .clear if you want to strip formatting as well
   else
       .cells.entirerow.delete
   end if
end with
```

If you want to avoid multiple row deletion on multiple row selection change `with selection` to `with selection.cells(1)`.